# How do I specify the include path when I build a program in VSCode?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

## Let's say this is my project.

file structure:

```
project_root
|-- inc
|   |-- header.h
|-- src
|   |-- helpers.c
|   |-- main.c
```

`header.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
# define HEADER_H

void    func(void);

#endif
```

`helpers.c`

```
void    func()
{
    /* do something */
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include "header.h"

int    main(void)
{
    func();
    return (0);
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/inc",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`tasks.json`

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-Werror",
                "-Wextra",
                "-o0"
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

## Issue

When I build my program in VSCode, I get the following error.
`project_root/src/main.c:xx:xx: fatal error: 'header.h' file not found`

## Question

How do I avoid this error?
(How do I let the VSCode's build feature know where my header is?)

## What I did already

I configured my include path(s) in `c_cpp_properties.json`, so I'm not getting the squiggles in `main.c`, where I include my header.

## What's not going to be a solution for me

I don't want to write `#include "../inc/header.h"` in `main.c`, so this would not be a solution for me.

Answer (score 11):

## specify the include paths in `tasks.json`, under the `args` property, using the `-I` flag.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-Wall",
                "-Werror",
                "-Wextra",
                "-o0",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/inc",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I did this and it still says: "No such file or directory".