# compiler cannot find head file in vscode

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-code

The project dir as follows:

```
-Project
|--lib
|--include
  |--GL
    |--glew.h
|--PBF_CUDA
  |--main.cpp
```

The `c_cpp_properties.json` like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/**",
                "D:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "D:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

When running this project, its got error:

```
[Running] cd "blabla" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "blabla/"main
In file included from main.cpp:4:
Renderer/RenderDevice.h:4:10: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glew.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.657 seconds
```

Something wrong is `IntelliSense` can find `GL/glew.h`, but compiler cannot find it.

How to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The ```GL/glew.h``` in project include folder not in ```D:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/include/GL```.

Comment: Does `#include "GL/glew.h"` work instead if `#include <GL/glew.h>`

Comment: Tried to change it to "", it also got other error ```RenderDevice.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^~~~
RenderDevice.h:4:10: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include "GL/glew.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```

Comment: You should add `-I` option. VS Code won't do it for you automatically. What is the contents of `tasks.json`?

Comment: Does any extendsion should be installed? Are there  some example?

Comment: ***Does any extendsion should be installed?*** No. This should help with the files: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand the overlap between `c_cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json`

Comment: @drescherjm, `c_cpp_*` is for IntelliSense, `tasks.json` is for compiler invocation.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096045/vscode-cannot-find-header-when-compile-while-intellisense-can) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219223/how-do-i-specify-the-include-path-when-i-build-a-program-in-vscode).

Comment: I had just found this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries)

Comment: The `tasks.json` just allows you to create tasks which you can map to keyboard shortcuts. So for example, you could set up a `task` to invoke your `compiler` and build your project. You can also set up `tasks` to do other stuff as well. I would also recommend learning and using `CMake`. It's helpful when projects become non-trivial